# How to modify a Joomla slider to put new images and a new description text?

Tags: slider

I have a site built in Joomla and I want to change the image of the slider and it's description text but I can't find it anywhere. I found the image from an article from carousel but the text description isn't there.

I saw that it is installed as a plugin, dj slider but only the image is there. Is it possible that the text description is in the database, cPanel?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed the English in your post so that it is easier for others to help you.  Please edit you post and tell us where you found the image and also a link to the article.  Again this will help others to help you faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DJ Image Slider is one of my personal favorites and once you get to know it, it works pretty well.

The first thing you'll need to do is go to `Components > DJ Image Slider` in your backend. From there, you can create a category (or several) under which your images can be categorized. Make sure they're set to "Published" if you need them to be.

Once that's done, you can create a new Slide, which will allow you to choose an image to display in the DJ Image Slider module.

From there, you can assign a title (which will be in larger font), then decide which category to put it under. You can input the desired text into "Slide Description", next to which there is a large text field. This is the text which will become the description under the title, so keep this fairly short. Make sure it's published, and make sure it's under a category of some kind.

However, they won't display unless your module is installed properly. So go to `Extensions > Modules` and search for the `DJ-ImageSlider` module. If one does not exist, create a new one. Then proceed to edit the module.

If you wish for the module to display the image under a specific category (which gives you more control), then set the Slider Source to `Component` and scroll down so you can choose which category of slides you want to be displayed. From there, you can play around with settings and module positioning. Remember to ensure that it's set to published and that viewing access is where you want it, and you should be good to go!